# setClass not found when running R script from command line

Tags: r, apache-storm, rscript

I have simple R script which trying to Define class.
      example.R

```
 Tuple <- setClass("Tuple",
            slots = c(
              id="character",
              comp="character",
              stream="character",
              task="character",
              output="vector",
              anchors="vector"
                )
            );
```

when i run Rscript example.R .
  i am getting an error saying below

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "setClass"
  Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

can any one help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rscript, in all its wisdom, does *not* load the standard `methods` package.  So precede your script with

```
library(methods)
```

and all should be good.

If you're on Linux, you could use our [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) package. It loads `methods` for you too, and starts a little faster than Rscript too.

*Edit* It is now some five years later and this has been added to `Rscript` in R release  3.5.0 or later.

Comment: Or call with the namespace: `methods::setClass(...`

Comment: As an additional note - if you have this problem when running checks on a package (if you're using devtools to run checks, for example) - you can add `import(methods)` to your NAMESPACE.